# Firefox 3 syntax error with external css

Tags: css, firefox, syntax-error, firefox-3

I get a strange syntax error in Firefox 3.0.10/Leopard when using the following html/css:

foo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
Foo
</body>
</html>
```

foo.css:

```
div {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

and the error I get in the console is:

```
Error: syntax error
Source File: file://path/to/foo.css
Line: 1, Column: 1
Source Code:
div {
```

It's not the CSS, because pasting it into the body of an inline STYLE tag works fine.
It's not the link tag, because pointing the HREF to stack overflow's css file doesn't give an error.
Feels like a Firefox bug, but I can't find any documentation on it.
Is this a known issue, and is there a workaround? It makes it hard to debug or validate.

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, that is not valid HTML, but I don't get that Firefox error in Firefox 3.0.9.  Try disabling all extensions.

Comment: That's a wierd one.Does it work if you put the stackoverflow css locally?

Comment: Matthew Flaschen got it.
The YSlow extension seems to be causing the issue.
Good to know for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be "Turn off extensions (it was YSlow)" as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you the error on the first character in the file, which is a 'd', which rules out things like "hidden" special characters to me. I'd guess that firefox isn't able to open the file locally for whatever reason, or that the file was accidentally saved with an encoding that, although it displays fine in the dialog box, doesn't parse normally. Perhaps it's saved as Unicode by mistake?

If you could link us to the actual file it would help, since your syntax (despite the markup not being exactly valid, but I don't think that's it) is perfect in the .css file you pasted in.

Comment: apphacker seems to have beaten me to the punch: sounds like the Unicode bom is what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Was the file written on windows? Maybe you need to reformat the carriage return/new line to mac os x. try running the file through something like dos2unix on the command line. Could also be a [bom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) you're not seeing.

Comment: nope - written in TextMate. Tried fooling with line endings anyway to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's some hidden character that might have been accidentally saved in the file. Try re-saving the CSS file, or re-typing the first line and then re-saving it.

Comment: Tried this too. retyped it all carefully, still get the error. And still no error when I cut and paste it into a script tag, which I would expect if I was picking up special characters. (the line number means nothing, I discovered - it always reports 1/1 for an external css file, no matter what line the actual error is on)

Answer (score 0):

If you're here from Google and working with local html, note that Firefox blocks requests for external CSS that use the `file://` protocol because it's technically a cross-origin request.

A quick fix is to serve the directory that contains your site to localhost over `http://`. If you have the python interpreter installed, you can do this very easily:

```
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

Then access localhost through your browser:

```
firefox localhost:8080
```

You can replace `8080` with any other port.